# Transpose columns to rows - SSMS 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, transpose

I am trying to figure out how to convert columns to rows in a T-SQL query. I have made a few attempts with pivots fairly unsuccessfully.

```
SELECT
    Open_Month
,   SUM(CASE WHEN [column] in 'column1' THEN 1 else 0) END AS [column1]
,   SUM(CASE WHEN [column] in 'column2' THEN 1 else 0) END AS [column2]
,   SUM(CASE WHEN [column] in 'column3' THEN 1 else 0) END AS [column3]
,   SUM(CASE WHEN [column] in 'column4' THEN 1 else 0) END AS [column4]
FROM
    tbl_Table1
GROUP BY
    Open_Month
```

The following query gives me the following returns.

[image: Current Output]

I am however going to be working with approximately 88 columns in total for a SSRS report which is going to be a barrel of laughs as I will have to make the columns visible based of User Input.

Because of the volume of the columns its impractical to attempt to display it natively and I am hoping to flip the columns and rows so it would look something like.

[image: Desired Output]

Any assistance with would be very kindly appreciated.

Comment: Seems to be it would be better to just do a simply count statement (e.g. `SELECT open_month, column, count(column) colcount FROM tblTable GROUP BY open_month, column`) and then build a matrix using the reporting services.

Comment: Mate....You are a legend. I am also slightly challenged today and in desperate need of a coffee.